# How can I require dependencies asynchronously but keeping them outside my bundle?

Tags: javascript, bundle, webpack

I'm trying to build an app that is able to fetch some dependencies from URLs on runtime.

I read about Wepback CommonsChunkPlugin but this forces you to get all dependencies so Wepback is able to create chunks properly. My point would be to get:

```
App.js
  \--> requires moduleA.js
  \--> requires moduleB.js
        \--> fetch moduleC async
```

So webpack (or whatever) will bundle module, moduleB and App but won't bundle moduleC that will be fetch it on runtime.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

`require.ensure` is your best bet. See [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). Here's rough usage:

```
require.ensure(["./moduleA", "./moduleA"], function(require) {
    var a = require("moduleA");
    // ...
});
```

You would have declarations like that at `App.js` and `moduleB.js`.

Comment: But webpack will need moduleA to do the bundle. I need them to be completely decoupled from moduleA in this case. Even better if I can fetch dependencies by URL.

Comment: You will need to use something like [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) if you want to deal with the latter case.